# Azure SIgnalR Service user credential validation before negotiation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-function-app, azure-signalr

We are trying to connect azure signalR service with our azure function app. We have a negotiate method in the function app that returns `SignalRConnectionInfo` object to client and before that, it makes a call to signalR service. We want to make a database call before making call to Azure signalR Service and returning `SignalRConnectionInfo` object. We are using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService 1.0.0` and Our negotiate function is like bellow

```
   [FunctionName("negotiate")]
    public static SignalRConnectionInfo GetSignalRInfo(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req,
        [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "simplechat", UserId = "{headers.x-ms-signalr-userid}")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        return connectionInfo;
    }
```

seems library is taking userid from header and passing to signalR service. Is there any way to execute some code before letting the library making call to signalR service?

In `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService 1.2.0` there are several ways to achieve this Like bellow.

```
 [FunctionName("negotiate")]
    public static SignalRConnectionInfo GetSignalRInfo(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        var userId = req.Query["userid"];
        var hubName = req.Query["hubname"];
        // Doing database check here 
        var connectionInfo = new SignalRConnectionInfo();
        var serviceManager = StaticServiceHubContextStore.Get().ServiceManager;
        connectionInfo.AccessToken = serviceManager
            .GenerateClientAccessToken(
                hubName,
                userId,
                new List<Claim> { new Claim("claimType", "claimValue") });
        connectionInfo.Url = serviceManager.GetClientEndpoint(hubName);
        return connectionInfo;
    }
```

Also by using class based hub

```
public class SimpleChat : ServerlessHub
{

    [FunctionName("negotiate")]
    public SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        // Doing Db check here
        return Negotiate(req.Headers["x-ms-signalr-user-id"], GetClaims(req.Headers["Authorization"]));
    }
```

I want to achieve similar functionality using 1.0.0 of the library. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I am struggling with exactly the same problem now.